# GOOGLETRANSLATE Function is not correctly translating some camelcase words

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I recently tried GOOGLETRANSLATE function to easiliy translate list of english string to 12 other languages. This is redundant work we do for every release, But I am noticing one weird issue like When I input "UnRetire" to the function and try to translate to spanish I am getting "Descripción" as the result.

GOOGLETRANSLATE("UnRetire","en","es") = Descripción

I know there is no such word "UnRetire" in english but If I try Google Translate it understands and translate accordingly

[image]

Is there any other function available to fix this kind of issues

Answer (score 1):

Despite performing multiple tests, I always get the same result, which indicates that Google is at fault here. To answer your question, only the `GOOGLETRANSLATE` function is built-in. However, there are other third-party add-ons you can use, one of which is [Sheets Translator](https://workspace.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/sheets_translator/684927618538), which you can find in the Google Workspace Marketplace.

[image]

The best we can do in this case is to submit feedback to the Google team so that they can address the incorrect result when using the `GOOGLETRANSLATE` function.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Reference:

- [GOOGLETRANSLATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en)